# Easy c++ gui for Xcode and installing GTK+

Tags: c++, xcode, user-interface, libraries

i wanted to make a Gui for a c++ program that prints code on a screen. My question is does anyone know a good library/program that is easy to understand. Also the install info for it due to the fact that i am not good at installing libraries. I know about GTK+ but the issue is that i have no idea how to install it. Mainly i just do not see the download link for it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This question is not a good fit, because asking for recommendations for a library or tool are no appropriate on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/macosx.html

try this. it's imho the best thing to learn